# Why do objects sometimes have outlines in Render Preview?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, interface

Sometimes in 3rd-party Blender files, objects will have black outlines in Cycles Render Preview. I want the outlines to go away, but I can't figure out how. What's causing them? Thanks. Blender 3.3.1, Windows 11

[image]

[blend](https://tinyurl.com/4jue2kur)

Comment: Probably because under object properties you set them to display was wireframe

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, when I look at Object Properties > Viewport Display, the only checkbox enabled is Shadow. Display As is set to Textured.

Comment: maybe share your blend file?

Comment: Have you enabled _Wireframe_ in the _Overlays_ for the _3D Viewport_? Although, then all objects should show wireframes...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, I'm not sure what you mean. I added a link to the partial blend file in my OP above.

Comment: I can't find any settings that are responsible for the wireframe. Although they can be turned off with the _Overlays_, they don't seem to be in any of the settings there. But if I select all objects, press _Tab_ to switch to _Edit Mode_ and then _Tab_ again to go back to _Object Mode_, the wireframes disappear. So to me it seems this is a kind of bug, either in Blender itself or the files are broken in some way, as if they were stuck in _Edit Mode_ display although being in _Object Mode_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, that's it. Select an object, toggle the Edit mode and the outlines disappear. Thank you! The file is 10 years old, so it's probably a version issue. I've run across this with other legacy Blender files too. (I'd mark your answer as the correct one, but there is no option to do so.)

Comment: No, because this is just the comment section, not an answer. I actually think this is too specific to be very helpful, since many beginners have problems with wireframe or not wireframe, but the reasons are mostly some settings, display modes etc. while your case might not apply very often. But you can answer the question yourself and accept that answer (after some time, usually to give others time to answer).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann IMO, others _might_  have this problem, with older files? Maybe it's preferable to post a brief answer and have it accepted, than to close the question.

Comment: @RobinBetts I don't mind anyone writing an answer and get it accepted. I'm very often opening old files from the past years and never experienced this problem so I wonder how common it is.